# JGIT Push takes a long time to add an empty commit (no changes) when executed from a Cloud system, but almost no time in a VM

Tags: java, kubernetes, jgit

**Context:**
I'm using JGIT 6.5.202303070854-r in a custom application that runs as a plugin inside another Java app inside Tomcat. For all intents and purposes it's a normal Java implementation.
The end result is that methods like Push and Pull are exposed as webservices

**Behavior:**
When this plugin is deployed in a cloud environment (which means the host app is deployed in a kubernetes architecture) what I observed is that even if Pull executes relatively ok, Push on the other hand executes **very slow**, making the webservice request timing out (socket timeout exception (read timeout)).

**What I tried:**
For reference, the same Push in my own local Tomcat instance executes in 5-6 seconds, while in cloud I sat once 15 minutes and it was still executing.I observed that essentially the commit is being pushed successfully with all its content, as far as I checked (though I did not do a binary check on the file count/contents)
All the tests I did were with empty commits and with a 22MB repo with 532 files with 5 commits.
I did observe that during the execution time, I have the following error:
".git/refs/remotes/origin/.probe-99c3f223-6a2c-4535-8c39-0c34f8f44ff6: Operation not permitted"
issued from JGit-FileStoreAttributeReader-2 (the thread name).
However this error does not happen all the time - last time the service executed successfully but in 5,8 minutes without any error.

I am currently in the process of retrieving the Kubernetes node logs to see if there's anything there that might point to this, **but if anyone encountered this I would be grateful to understand why that happens**.

The Push implementation is this, in case it matters, wrapper in a try/catch:

```
myGitFolder.add().addFilepattern(".").setUpdate(true).call();
 myGitFolder.commit().setAll(true).setMessage(Message).setCommitter(str_CommitterName, str_CommitterEmail).call();

CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(str_User, str_Password);

Iterable<PushResult> prList = myGitFolder.push().setRemote("origin")
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
```

**Expectation:**
I'm expecting to have Push with the above implementation execute in under 10 seconds with an empty commit.

Comment: For everyone who experienced this, an additional point we were able to see by logging is the fact that the add and commit seem to take the most time (70 seconds each with an empty commit), not Push itself. Still unclear for us what is the reason both take such a long time

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update for whoever hits this issue in the future.
The slowness exhibited in my case is due to three compound aspects:

- the frequent file read/write operations executed by the Java JGIT library when pushing data (even with an empty commit)
- a large file count (started being visible after 80 files per repo)
- use of Azure Files for file persistence in the kubernetes architecture my app is hosted. They mention this issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/files-troubleshoot-performance?tabs=linux#high-latencies-for-metadata-heavy-workloads-involving-extensive-openclose-operations.